# Why do std::adressof() behaves like this on invalid inputs?

Tags: c++, pointers

So say I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << std::addressof(input) << endl;
    main(argc, argv);
}
```

If you give it a valid int input it will just print a normal adress, however, if you give it a invalid value (i.e "this is a string value", "kasdkjadlksnkqlw~" or 9999999999999999999) it will keep printing adresses.

Why does it behaves like this? Is this a so called buffer overflow?
EXTRA: How do I enable syntax highlighting on this website?

Comment: UB calling `main`. What happens when you remove the call?

Comment: Recursive `main`. That's something I haven't seen before.

Comment: @user4581301 Really? I do that all the time on small programs, it seems to be a bad pratice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's call the function `meow` (or throw it into a namespace), because using `::main` makes the program ill-formed.

```
int meow(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << std::addressof(input) << endl;
    meow(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

A failed stream extraction sets `failbit` on the stream. Later extraction operations on that stream will immediately fail without blocking for input, so you end up in (obvious) infinite recursion printing addresses over and over again.

(Your code has infinite recursion any way; the only difference is that it's not as apparent when `cin >> input` blocks.)